# Problem with Packettracer

Tags: xubuntu, software-uninstall, cisco

I need some help with Packettracer, I've alredy installed Packet Tracer 6.3 and 7.1 but they didn't work and now I want to get rid of them both. It didn't work with purge or deleting the /opt/pt/ and some other librarys I don't know what to do now...

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: How did you install Packet Tracer 6.3 and 7.1 ? You need to undo that process.

Comment: I downloaded the packages from cisco and used the installsckript

Comment: Then read the install script, and see if it has an option to uninstall, or if there's an "uninstall" script in the same directory